# Which javascript library for mysql access can you recommend?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am using JavaScript standalone, not running in a browser.

I want to connect to a mysql server running on the same host.

Is there a JavaScript library for this?

*Edit*: I had a look at Jaxer. It has mysql functionality, but it is baked into the framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're referring to server-side Javascript, Jaxer:

http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/javascript-mysql-with-jaxer/

Otherwise Javascript is mainly used for client side scripting. Though you can utilize XMLHttpRequest and hit a server-side page that can do the backend interaction to access a db.

Answer (score 0):

`npm search mysql` shows a number of libraries, both straight drivers and ORMs. It looks like the fastest server-side one would be either `mysql-libmysqlclient` or `db-mysql`. See also the MySQL section of https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules